# How to separately recognize the data sent over to php?

Tags: php, javascript

I am sending two data to my php from my javascript:
http://forum.research.bell-labs.com/zeeshan/publication/phpwithmysql11111.php?rowid=BL09.00001,0

1) BL09.00001
2) 0

How do I recognize them separately in my php? 
I was trying to do:

$job=$_GET[rowid];
echo($job);

this gives me both the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you need to name the second parameter as well as the first in your GET request.

Use a URL like this: http://forum...../phpwithmysql11111.php?rowid=BL09.00001&other=1

Then, $_GET['rowid'] should be BL09.00001 and $_GET['other'] should be 1.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I wanted to do the same, but i was not able to. my javascript code looks like this:

function show(jobno,arrno) {
  window.open(
       'phpwithmysql11111.php?rowid='+jobno,    
       'tesing','status=0,width=100,height=100'    
     );
     return false;
}

what should i change in it to make it work like that?

Comment: it looks like both values are contained in the jobno variable in your javascript.  If that is the case, you need to split them at some point, either on the javascript side, or the PHP side.  Check out @dxmio above for how to do it in PHP, or for javascript try:
'phpwithmysql11111.php?rowid='+jobno.split(',')[0]+'&other='+jobno.split(',')[1] for the first parameter to your window.open call.

Answer (score 4):

Just split $GET['rowid'] on the comma. See:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php